# Batch copy and rename with appended filename

Tags: windows, batch-processing, file-rename

I am trying to duplicate a file several times, each time appending the filename with an integer (0001, 0002, 0003 ...)

I am looking to create a work log sheet for each system in our office (50 something systems). Systems are named ST0001 - ST0050. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the prompt, assuming ST0001.xslx exists:

```
for /L %i in (2,1,9) do copy /B ST0001.xlsx ST000%i.xlsx >nul
for /L %i in (1,10,50) do copy /B ST0001.xlsx ST00%i.xlsx >nul
```

(naturally, add any required prefix to ST???? if necessary. Insufficient info (like a complete example) to assist further)

Comment: More info:     need to duplicate ST0001.xlsx -> ST0002, ST0003...ST0050